# Why there should be exactly one QApplication

Tags: qt

Here is a quote from Qt documentation:

> For any GUI application using Qt, there is precisely one QApplication object

It's quite clear. But I couldn't figure out why. 
I was asked such a question during an interview, and now I can't find a proper answer, could anyone explain me please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`QCoreApplication` documentation gives a hint:

> QCoreApplication contains the main event loop, where all events from
>   the operating system (e.g., timer and network events) and other
>   sources are processed and dispatched. It also handles the
>   application's initialization and finalization, as well as system-wide
>   and application-wide settings.

And only one event loop can run at any given time (in a single thread), so the distinct `QCoreApplication` objects would need to invoke each other. When processing event queues, each would only see parts of the whole interaction. Does not seem attractive to me...

Also, I think, the `QCoreApplication` is basically the abstraction of the whole process, so it makes sense to enforce a 1:1 correspondence between Qt processes and `QCoreApplication` objects.

Technically, things like `QCoreApplication::instance()` or the respective `qApp` macro obviously need a single `QCoreApplication` instance.

Answer (score 1):

`QApplication` contains several singletons, as the message loop and others.